# getting a jquery form to display on a jsfiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery

learning JS/Jquery and im answering the Q...

https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9909

> The createProductCodeForm function is used to create a new form that accepts a product code from a user.
>
> The current version of the form contains the hint: 'The product code can be found on the label'. This hint is currently always visible to the user.
>
> Improve the form so that the hint is only rendered when the input element is the focused element.

So I know its to do with the `focus()` but before I get that far I want to create  a JSfiddle where I can play about with and maybe amend once I get the answer but im having difficulty getting it to display. I want to display the form on the bottom right screen on the fiddle

So far ive got...

https://jsfiddle.net/cue47utt/3/

Do I attach the id to the form or how can I get the form to display on the output screen (bottom right) on the js fiddle

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("hi");
  var form = $("<form/>");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append($("<input>").attr('name', 'productCode').attr('type', 'text'));
  form.append($("<label>").attr('name', 'hint').text('The product code can be found on the label.'));

  form.append('<br>');

  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));

  parent.append(form);
}

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="form1">

</div>
```

Please forgive if its something simple...in the learning stages
Thank Yo

Comment: look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cue47utt/5/)

Comment: ahh excellent man thanks for your help..now what about adding the focus() do I just add it in and the functionality?

Comment: I made an answer below.. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var form = $("form");

  form.append("<label>Product Code:</label><input name='productCode' type='text'><label name='hint' class='hint'>The product code can be found on the label.</label><br><input type='submit'>");
      $(".hint").hide();
}

 $(document).on("focus","input",function(){
      $(".hint").show();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<form id="form1">
  <!-- how do I add the form to the div to load here when i click 'click me' -->

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var $input;
  var $hint;
  var form = $("<form />");

  form.append($("<label>").text('Product Code:'));
  form.append($input = $("<input>").attr('name', 'productCode').attr('type', 'text'));
  form.append($hint = $("<label style='display:none;'>").attr('name', 'hint').text('The product code can be found on the label.'));

  form.append('<br>');

  form.append($("<input>").attr('type', 'submit'));

  $('#form1').append(form);
  $input.on('focus', function() {
      $hint.show();
  });
  $input.on('blur', function() {
      $hint.hide();
  });
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="form1">
<!-- how do I add the form to the div to load here when i click 'click me' -->

</div>
```

Comment: No this is not correct the hint should only be displayed when the text box in in focus

Comment: Now, I modified, is this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `ES6` template literals. Check this  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cue47utt/7/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('#form1').append(`
    <label>Product Code:</label>
      <input name='productCode' type='text' />
      <label name='hint'>The product code can be found on the label.</label>
      <br />
      <input type='submit' />`
  );
  
  $('input[name="productCode"]').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="form1">
<!-- how do I add the form to the div to load here when i click 'click me' -->

</div>
```

Hope this will help you.